# Update IdentityServer from .net7 to .net8

Tags: .net, asp.net-identity, .net-8.0

Does anyone know if there is a way to update IdentityServer from a .net7 hosted Webassembly app to a .net8 WebApp? I'm currently using Microsoft.AspNetCore.ApiAuthorization.IdentityServer, and there's no version beyond. 7.0.14

Read all about updating to .net8 in the Microsoft docs, but can't find any mention of Identity in them.